# is there an example repo to try Calva with Figwheel-Main?

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

could you please point me in the right direction: 
i've been successfully using calva with old figwheel, but  cannot connect to figwheel-main.. (have no problems connecting to shadow-cljs ).

i've been failing for a while now. what i do: select 'Figwheel Main' and specify localhost:port (e.g. 9500).

anyway, the question: is there a demo repo (maybe  https://github.com/PEZ/fresh-figwheel-main) that i can try with calva and figwheel-main ? what host:port should i type in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved, steps to connect:

https://github.com/BetterThanTomorrow/calva/issues/296#issuecomment-526898449